# .net don't run tests not in a list

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I have placed 6 unit tests into an ordered test.  Run All Tests in solution runs the ordered test which passes, but continues to run the 6 tests individually, which causes some of them to fail.  How can I force it to not run these tests?  It seems disabling them also disables them in the ordered test.

Comment: Can you use a different test runner? Have you considered trying something like http://www.ncrunch.net/ ? It does not have the problems that VS test runner has, plus it has many more features, like live coverage statistics and continuous unit testing.